# Creating new columns in R data set within function

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataset for a class that I'm taking, which comes from the UCI Machine Learning repository. I have to subset it by date, and then plot various measurements by date and time. To prep the dataset, I use the following code:

```
prep <- function(x) {
  setwd("/Users/johnlynch/Google Drive/DataToolbox/Exploring/Week 1")
  power <- read.csv("poweruse.txt", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  power$Date <- strptime(power$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
  power <- subset(power, Date == "2007-02-01"|Date == "2007-02-02")
}
```

Then, when I run my script in the console, I type "power <- prep()" and the subsetted data is put into the variable "power," exactly as I expect:

> head(mydata)
>
> Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
>
> 66637 2007-02-01 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128 243.150            1.400          0.000 66637          0.000              0
>
> 66638 2007-02-01 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130 243.320            1.400          0.000 66638          0.000              0
>
> 66639 2007-02-01 00:02:00               0.324                 0.132 243.510            1.400          0.000 66639          0.000              0
>
> 66640 2007-02-01 00:03:00               0.324                 0.134 243.900            1.400          0.000 66640          0.000              0
>
> 66641 2007-02-01 00:04:00               0.322                 0.130 243.160            1.400          0.000 66641          0.000              0
>
> 66642 2007-02-01 00:05:00               0.320                 0.126 242.290            1.400          0.000 66642          0.000              0

However, I discovered as I did the plots that, in order to match the course plots, I needed to create a new column in the dataframe, $newdate, by combining the Date and Time columns into one. So I tried adjusting my script to be as follows:

```
prep <- function(x) {
  setwd("/Users/johnlynch/Google Drive/DataToolbox/Exploring/Week 1")
  power <- read.csv("poweruse.txt", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  power$Date <- strptime(power$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
  power <- subset(power, Date == "2007-02-01"|Date == "2007-02-02")
  power$newDate <- with(power, paste(Date, Time))
}
```

I thought, hey, that should create a new column in the dataframe that would be output along with the rest of the data into the mydata variable. However, when I run that function, the ONLY output that I get is the contents of the $newdate column:

> head(mydata)
>
> [1] "2007-02-01 00:00:00" "2007-02-01 00:01:00" "2007-02-01 00:02:00" "2007-02-01 00:03:00"
>
> [5] "2007-02-01 00:04:00" "2007-02-01 00:05:00"

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the second script output the entire dataset, with a new column added at the end? And can someone tell me how to correct that?

Comment: Add `return(power)` (or just `power`) to the last line of your function.

Comment: Weihuang has it correct. A function only returns the object in the last line of code. In your case it was just creating a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function in R returns the last expression that is evaluated.  Consider these two functions:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  x$a <- 2
  x
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  x$a <- 2
}
```

Given a list, `f1` will return a list, whereas `f2` will return a numeric vector of length 1 (the number 2):

```
> x <- list(a = 1)
> str(f1(x))
List of 1
 $ a: num 2
> str(f2(x))
 num 2
>
```

For more details, Hadley Wickham's [tutorial on functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) is worth reading.

Comment: That exactly solved it! Thank you for explaining it so clearly, and I will read Wickham's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In R function,if you do not use return,R will **return** the last line code as default.
So never forget to add return for the results you want.

```
prep <- function(x) {
  setwd("/Users/johnlynch/Google Drive/DataToolbox/Exploring/Week 1")
  power <- read.csv("poweruse.txt", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  power$Date <- strptime(power$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
  power <- subset(power, Date == "2007-02-01"|Date == "2007-02-02")
  power$newDate <- with(power, paste(Date, Time))
  return(power)
}
```